# Why is my custom function not working with Timber?

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I'm trying to add a custom function to Timber and i'm unable to get it to work. I'm new to Timber and currently playing with the timber starter theme to get my head around how it works. I've got the example function to show but my custom function doesn't show.

I've tried following the instructions from the Timber docs and playing around with the answers given here: [Using custom functions with Timber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467244/using-custom-functions-with-timber) all with no luck.

Here is my function in my functions.php file (works fine in a theme without Timber).

```
function prev_next_titled_pagination() {
    // Don't print empty markup if there's only one page.
    if ( $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages < 2 ) {
        return;
    } ?>

        <nav aria-label="pagination">
        <ul class="post-navigation">
            <?php if ( get_next_posts_link() ) : ?>
                <li class="post-navigation__item post-navigation__item--previous"><?php get_next_post_link( __( '<span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span>' %title ) ); ?></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) : ?>
                <li class="post-navigation__item post-navigation__item--next"><?php get_previous_post_link( __( '%title <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span>' ) ); ?></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<?php
}
```

Here's whats in my functions.php file within the StarterSite object. The 'myfoo' function works.

```
/** This is where you can add your own functions to twig.
*
* @param string $twig get extension.
*/
public function add_to_twig( $twig ) {
    $twig->addExtension( new Twig_Extension_StringLoader() );
    $twig->addFilter( new Twig_SimpleFilter( 'myfoo', array( $this, 'myfoo' ) ) );
    $twig->addFilter( new Twig_SimpleFilter( 'prev_next_titled_pagination', array( $this, 'prev_next_titled_pagination' ) ) );
    return $twig;
}
```

And here is how I'm calling the function in my single.twig file. 'myfoo' works. 'prev_next_titled_pagination' does not.

```
{{ function( 'prev_next_titled_pagination' ) }}
{{ function('myfoo', 'HI' ) }}
```

I get no errors with this code but nothing outputs either. Trying other suggestions from the docs gives me errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your function is not working, because the `array( $this, 'prev_next_titled_pagination' )` callback that you add for `prev_next_titled_pagination` is a method of your `StarterSite` class. But when you add `prev_next_titled_pagination()` as a normal function your functions.php file, when Twig will not find that function.

I also see that you add your function as a filter. This means that you would normally use it with Twig’s filter notation, using `|myfoo` or `|prev_next_titled_pagination`. I think you wanted to add a function.

You probably don’t need the `Twig_Extension_StringLoader` extension either. That’s just used as an example.

Here’s you updated Twig filter:

```php
/**
 * This is where you can add your own functions to twig.
 *
 * @param string $twig get extension.
 */
public function add_to_twig( $twig ) {
    $twig->addFunction( new Timber\Twig_Function( 'myfoo', array( $this, 'myfoo' ) ) );
    $twig->addFunction( new Timber\Twig_Function( 'prev_next_titled_pagination', 'prev_next_titled_pagination' ) );

    return $twig;
}
```

You could also rewrite your template and convert it to Twig completely instead of relying on a `prev_next_titled_pagination()` function. A Timber post has the `post.next` and `post.prev` functions that you can use for this:

```
{% if post.prev or post.next %}
    <nav aria-label="pagination">
        <ul class="post-navigation">
            {% if post.next %}
                <li class="post-navigation__item post-navigation__item--previous">
                    <a href="{{ post.next.link }}"><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> {{ post.next.title }}</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}

            {% if post.prev %}
                <li class="post-navigation__item post-navigation__item--next">
                    <a href="{{ post.prev.link }}">{{ post.prev.title }} <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </nav>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gchtr. I didn't have any luck with your first suggestion - 'myfoo' works both ways (filter and function) but neither worked with 'prev_next_titled_pagination. I tried it both within and out of the StarterSite method and both didn't work. 'myfoo' however works in both places! I've gone with your second suggestion and it works great for this example so thank you for that. I was using a function as it's a function in my non timber theme so the code is only in one place but for timber this seems like a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Functions should return a value, also don't break up your function like that...

```
<?php
    function prev_next_titled_pagination() {
        // Don't print empty markup if there's only one page.
        if ( $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages < 2 ) return;
        $html = '<nav aria-label="pagination"><ul class="post-navigation">';
        if (get_next_posts_link()) $html .= '<li class="post-navigation__item post-navigation__item--previous">'.get_next_post_link( __( '<span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> %title')).'</li>';
        if (get_previous_posts_link()) $html .= '<li class="post-navigation__item post-navigation__item--next">'.get_next_post_link( __( '%title <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span>')).'</li>';
        $html .= '</ul></nav>';

        return $html; // or return new \Twig_Markup($html, 'UTF-8'); if you did not mark your output as safe in the registration
    }
```

---

imho you are better of aliasing the functions `get_next_posts_link` and `get_previous_posts_link` and use those directly in your template instead of trying to do this in one big chunk

Comment: Thanks for this. It didn't solve the issue but I appreciate the feedback. I think what you're saying about aliasing is the same as what @Gchtr has suggested which is the route I've taken for this so thanks for that too.